# Rotation and Transformation of a plane to XY plane and origin in PointCloud

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, point-cloud-library, eigen3

I have a point cloud that is *known* to contain the floor. This is oriented in some unknown direction and is *not* at the origin (0,0,0). I have to

- move the `floor_plane` to XY plane, so that the `floor_plane` lies on XY plane
- move the centroid of `floor_plane` to the origin `(0,0,0)`.

My approach for the above is:

- Get the plane coefficients of `floor_plane` from RANSAC. First three coefficients correspond to the `floor_plane`'s normal.
- Generate the normal vector for XY plane. This would be x=0,y=0 and z=1.
- Calculate cross product of normal of ground plane and normal of xy plane to get rotation vector (axis) which is a unit vector.
- Calculate the rotation angle. Angle between the planes is equal to angle between the normals. From the definition of the dot product, we can extract the angle between two normal vectors. In case of XY plane, it is equal to `theta=acos(C/sqrt(A^2+B^2+C^2)` where A, B, C are first three coefficients of `floor_plane`.
- Generate the rotation matrix (3x3) or quaternion. Look for the formula in Wikipedia.
- Find the centroid of `floor_plane`. Negate them to generate the translation
- Apply the transformation simply with transformPointCloud(cloud,transformed,transformationMatrix)

My code using PointCloud Library goes as follows. It is unable to perform the required transformation, and I am not sure why. Any clues?

```
      // Find the planar coefficients for floor plane
      pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
      pcl::PointIndices::Ptr floor_inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
      pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> seg;
      seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
      seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
      seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
      seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);
      seg.setInputCloud (floor_plane);
      seg.segment (*floor_inliers, *coefficients);
      std::cerr << "Floor Plane Model coefficients: " << coefficients->values[0] << " "
                                        << coefficients->values[1] << " "
                                        << coefficients->values[2] << " "
                                        << coefficients->values[3] << std::endl;

      Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 3> floor_plane_normal_vector, xy_plane_normal_vector, rotation_vector;

      floor_plane_normal_vector[0] = coefficients->values[0];
      floor_plane_normal_vector[1] = coefficients->values[1];
      floor_plane_normal_vector[2] = coefficients->values[2];

      std::cout << floor_plane_normal_vector << std::endl;

      xy_plane_normal_vector[0] = 0.0;
      xy_plane_normal_vector[1] = 0.0;
      xy_plane_normal_vector[2] = 1.0;

      std::cout << xy_plane_normal_vector << std::endl;

      rotation_vector = xy_plane_normal_vector.cross (floor_plane_normal_vector);
      std::cout << "Rotation Vector: "<< rotation_vector << std::endl;

      float theta = acos(floor_plane_normal_vector.dot(xy_plane_normal_vector)/sqrt( pow(coefficients->values[0],2)+ pow(coefficients->values[1],2) + pow(coefficients->values[2],2)));


  Eigen::Affine3f transform_2 = Eigen::Affine3f::Identity();
  transform_2.translation() << 0, 0, 30;
  transform_2.rotate (Eigen::AngleAxisf (theta, rotation_vector));
  std::cout << "Transformation matrix: " << std::endl << transform_2.matrix() << std::endl;
  pcl::transformPointCloud (*cloud, *centeredCloud, transform_2);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your step of  approach helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted with this code? I was unable to do so and later changed it to something else, which worked.

Comment: If I want to get the rotation to another axis (for example y axis) I have to change the xy_plane_normal_vector[1] to 1.0 and xy_plane_normal_vector[2] to 0.0? Do I have to change anything else?

Comment: Hi @PranavPrakash, what was the other solution you got that worked? Can you share the details ? Thanks!

Comment: @ManJan I tried the approach mentioned by otna_ecnav below and it worked,

Comment: @pr4n could you provide your final corrected code

Comment: @isht - Unfortunately I don't have the source with me now, but I believe I tried the response from otna_ecnav below and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the translation first, then do the rotation.

Check the sign of theta

```
Eigen::Vector3f rotation_vector = xy_plane_normal_vector.cross(floor_plane_normal_vector);
float theta = -atan2(rotation_vector.norm(), xy_plane_normal_vector.dot(floor_plane_normal_vector));
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is interested

There were 2 problems in the code

1. Rotation vector need to be normalized (just call rotation_vector.normalized() in the line *transform_2.rotate (Eigen::AngleAxisf (theta, rotation_vector));*)
2. angle need to be negated (as suggested by previous answer).

Thank you for posting the code, it helped me to finish this quickly.